# How can I display an array of strings in a certain way inside a TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, formatting

I am doing a graduation project on Machine Translation to translate from any language into English language.

My software accepts a string in the source language (SL) and then under each source language word it displays all the meanings ordered according to their probabilities.. something looks like this

```
Word1      Word2     Word3
hit        bell      man
multiply             leg
```

The issue is that I have to display the meanings of the first word then I have to go back to the first line to display the meanings of the second word and so on... **in the same TextBox!**

Is there a way in c# by which I can go back to the first line and write next to existing words?

Comment: That sounds like it'd going to be very awkward. Why are you doing your work against a string array rather then in memory structures that can be transformed into a string for presentation ?

Comment: I think you're going to have to be a little more specific.  First of all: what type of application is this?  I'm guessing it's not a console application, since you mention a "textbox."  Is that actually a requirement or does it just need to look a certain way when all is said and done?  Also, to clarify, do you mean that you need to display columns for each word and then populate those columns with meanings as the application runs?

Comment: @asawyer actually I'am using array of array to store the results. Each array inside the jagged array stores the meanings of each word in order. but I also find it difficult to display it in the way I need.

Comment: You might want to create a new control that just creates textboxes with 0 border. That way each column is simply a borderless multiline textbox. And when you add a new column, your control simply adds a new textbox. You can also use the FlowLayoutPanel to automate your layout additions. If you have the freedom to do this, it would be easier than hacking around in a textbox.

Comment: @StevenOxley It is a windows based application.it just need to look a certain way when all is said and done.."do you mean that you need to display columns for each word and then populate those columns with meanings as the application runs?" No the displaying part is the done lastly after finishing calculations.

Comment: @Jason I think your idea is perfect but I don't now if it is going to work in my situation because I have to host the software on the web and the interface (only one textbox) should be static.

Comment: So it's ASP.NET and not WinForms?

Comment: @Noha I don't have a complete answer for you, but what you're describing can probably be done extremely easily using HTML tables.  You might want to check them out (just google for an HTML table tutorial - there're tons out there).  I believe they were designed to specifically solve the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

You can control cursor position (and selection) by `TextBox.SelectionStart` and `TextBox.SelectionLength` properties.

Example if you want move cursor to before 3th character set `SelectionStart = 2` and `SelectionLength = 0`.

So, as a - assuming Windows Forms Application - solution to your issue

```
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    public TextBoxEx()
    { }

    public void GoTo(int line, int column)
    {
        if (line < 1 || column < 1 || this.Lines.Length < line)
            return;

        this.SelectionStart = this.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line - 1) + column - 1;
        this.SelectionLength = 0;
    }

    public int CurrentColumn
    {
        get { return this.SelectionStart - this.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine() + 1; }
    }

    public int CurrentLine
    {
        get { return this.GetLineFromCharIndex(this.SelectionStart) + 1; }
    }
}
```

---

OR

Just add this class to your project,

```
public static class Extentions
{
    public static void GoTo ( this TextBox Key , int Line , int Character )
    {
        if ( Line < 1 || Character < 1 || Key . Lines . Length < Line )
            return;

        Key . SelectionStart = Key . GetFirstCharIndexFromLine ( Line - 1 ) + Character - 1;
        Key . SelectionLength = 0;
        Key . Focus ( );
    }
}
```

After adding this class to your project, you can easily navigate your TextBox by

```
TextBox . GoTo ( 1 , 1 ); // Navigate to the 1st line and the 1st character :)
```

Hope this help.

Comment: sounds helpful.. I'll try it and let you know.. Thanks

Comment: Edit I : Adding go to line and column support :)

Comment: @asawyer what do you main by Winforms?? do you mean windows forms?

Comment: @Noha, Yes Noha Windows Forms Application

Comment: @Noha You said "I have to host the software on the web" and Ahmed posted "So, as a - assuming Windows Forms Application"  A winforms textbox is *not* the same as an asp.net/html textbox, so sadly this sample will not help you. (If you are in fact hosting on the web)

Comment: @asawyer ops :( so, is there a way to solve my issue for asp.net texbox because I will use asp.net to connect the services of my sofware( Iam planning to devlop it as a web service)

Comment: Edit 2 : Adding extension to easily navigate through your TextBox

Comment: @Noha You'll have to do your manipulations on the raw string, then assign it to the textbox on postback.

Comment: @asawyer postback? can you explain a little more, please excuse my stupidity

Comment: @Noha That is far beyond the scope of these comments.